# How to have load balancing using 1 Ethernet card + 2 ADSL router

Tags: networking, load-balancing, router, adsl, ubuntu-12.10

I have 1 Ubuntu 12.10 server with 1 eth0 (192.168.0.100) and it's connected to my switch. In my network I have 2 ADSL routers (192.168.0.1 & 192.168.0.101).

How I can configure my server to act as load balanced router (all PCs conected to 192.168.0.100 as gateway) to gain more bandwith or mix bandwith (2 x 4M) ?

Or there is a cheap hardware to do that like PCs -> box -> ADSL1 AND/OR ADSL2 ?

Comment: Real load balancing or just http traffic for example?

Comment: It's more for common http/s trafic but if I have a solution for all kind of trafics why not ?

Answer (score 2):

Just google for `linux multipath routing`, there are plenty of how-to's.

Comment: thanks to give me the right keywords for my search, but I only found examples on multiple Ethernet cards and not on 1 card only. Can you point me to a more specific link ?

Comment: You can create multiple aliases for your network device, so it doesn't matter if you are just using one (physical) interface. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/

Comment: Thanks Henry, I know how create virtual interface, but I don"t know how to add a specific route on the C & B interface and use A as gateways for other PCs who will be routed using C & B dynamically.

Comment: Henry : following  http://www.debian-administration.org/article/377/Routing_for_multiple_uplinks

ip route add default scope global \
nexthop via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0:1 weight 1 \
nexthop via 192.168.0.101 eth0:2 weight 1

Virtual IP seem not work with error message :  Error: "nexthop" or end of line is expected instead of "eth0:2"

Comment: ip route add default scope global nexthop via $GW1 dev $IF1 weight 1 nexthop via $GW2 **dev** $IF2 weight 1
http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html#AEN267